# Given this definition, can we have an $n$-dimension manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is the definition given:

$M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $k$-dimension manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for all $x \in M$, there exists:

1) $k$ standard basis vectors that, near $x$, determine the values of the $n-k$ variables. Denote by $E_1$ the span of these, and $E_2$ the span of the remaining standard basis vectors, let $x_1$ be the projection of $x$ onto $E_1$ and $x_2$ the projection of $x$ onto $E_2$.

2) A neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

3) A neighborhood $U_1$ of $x_1$ in $E_1$

4) A mapping $f:U_1 \to E_2$.

Does this definition work in the case that $k=n$, so $n-k=0$? i.e. can we have a $2$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or a $3$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes. For example the unit disk is a 2-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The unit disk with or without its boundary?

Comment: If you include the boundary, it is a manifold with boundary. Without boundary, it is just a manifold.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathbb R^n$ itself is an $n$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Continuing the question then, what is the tangent space to an $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$? The $0$-vector space? The definition given is that it is the graph of $[Dg(x)]$ where $g:U_1 \to E_2$ is a $C^1$ function and $U_1$, $E_2$ defined above. But in this case it seems that $E_2=\{0\}$ so the tangent space of an $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. An open $n$-ball (embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is an $n$-manifold.